# Need to specify max length for numeric filed type in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, erb, simple-form-for

I need to restrict the user from entering the only integer for one of my column with length specification.

`<%= f.input :value, as: :numeric, :input_html => { :maxlength => 4 } %>`

The above works for string type of field in the UI, but when I add numeric to restrict alphanumeric input, then the max length is not working.

the expectation is to limit the input to 4 char maximum, and it should be positive number input only

Answer (score 0):

If your "value" attribute is an integer you don't need to specify the "as" in simpleform as it will automagically handle that for you:

```
<%= f.input :value, as: :integer, input_html: { min: '0', max: '9999', step: '1' } %> 
#If you want decimals you can change :step to 'any'
```

My personal preference is to use jquery-mask: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html

In your view you then apply it like (assuming turbolinks wasn't disabled):

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('#input-id-here').mask('0000');
})
```

Comment: bkunzi01 `value` is of type string.

Comment: Thank you @ bkunzi01, but `min` and `max` are not working because I'm able to update more than 4 digits

Comment: The easiest solution then would be to use a validation in your model and add a jquery mask to your view. I use this plugin for masking: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html  I'll add it to the bottom of the answer since it will do what you need but isn't exactly what you're looking for.